# How to use SWT Spy for SWT applications?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have seen [SWT Spy](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/tools.php) and want to debug my SWT application. However I was only able to spy on eclipse itself. That is when SWT Spy was active and the mouse was hovering over eclipse it printed debug information into the SWT Spy view, but when I moved the mouse over my application there was no output.

Can one use SWT Spy with a (standalone) SWT program too? If so, how does one set it up?

Comment: Have you included in your application the spy plug-in org.eclipse.swt.spy_*.jar ?

Answer (score 2):

SWT Spy was implemented as plugin with `View` to show debug information. Problem is that the View has most of the logic to print debug information. So you can't use spy plugin in your SWT application.

org.eclipse.swt.spy_*.jar has source code attached, extract it. I would suggest you to get the source code and customize it as per your needs.